# Production Mode Slower than Developer mode? How can this be?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento-2.2.1

EDIT:

```
Developer Mode: Waiting TTFB => 121ms
Production Mode: Waiting TTFB => 224ms
```

(It's the first html that loads, the page) It's that delay I feel when browsing.

While using Magento 2.2.1, page load is 200ms slower in production mode than developer mode.

In developer mode, the website feels also faster, which is weard.

Using Chrome DevTools **Dom Content Load** is 624ms on dev vs it is 830ms on prod. In addition, the total loading time is 1.44sec on dev and 1.6-1.7sec on prod.

**Any idea why this happens?**

I have enabled minification of CSS and javascript.

PS: I also feel a difference when using in developer mode. It's not just the 200ms. It just feels instant. "With production mode" I feel "a delay after the mouse click on links. (like this ms delay).

I'm confused, normally the production mode should be faster.

Maybe I need to adjust some settings on the server?

Comment: Everything is the same except you are changing `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It does minify javascript en css in production mode. Even if i disable minify it's still the same.

Comment: Have you added any custom theme or any custom module that load on the home page. Could you share dev url so I can see and suggest you.

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
top        for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @Fancyman Have you found a solution to this? I'm facing exactly the same issue. that my website has a better TTFB in developer mode than production mode.

Comment: Facing the same issue.. Any workaround? @MagentoLearner

Comment: any solution ? i have same issue

Answer (score 1):

"since years" (M2.1.x, M2.2.x, M2.3.x) production mode is slower. We run only in development mode.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. :-D My experience is just the same, with developer mode performing better in terms of page load times.

Comment: is there any official comment on this, or other info that might explain why dev mode runs faster?